# Getting Accuracy from a pre trained SVM for image classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a pre trained image classification model and I'm feeding it new images. I can get a  prediction just fine, but how can I get the accuracy of this prediction or is this even possible? Below is what I'm trying to accomplish. I checked sklearn but couldn't find anything relevant. the img will be (80,80) and will be reshaped to (1,6400) for the protection.

```
def f(img):
   filename = "SVM_model.sav"
   with open(filename, 'rb') as file1:
       SV = pickle.load(file1)
   p = SV.predict(img)
   accuracy = ????
   return p and accuracy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the accuracy, you need to have the real class of your predictions. I think that you rather want to know how confident you are in the prediction. For that, you can use the method `SV.predict_proba(img)` instead of `SV.predict(img)`

Comment: yes that's exactly what im looking for. thank you!